# find the cells that reach to certain mount excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

there are multiple cells with numbers in a range.
I want to mark the cells which sum of them will reach to a certain number.
For example: this code will find just two cells, but I need at least 30 cells

```
For each cell1 in range("A1:A30")
  For each cell2 in range("A1:A30")
    If cell1.value+cell2.value= MyNumber then
      Cell1.interior.color=vbRed
      Cell2.interior.color=vbRed
      Exit sub
    End if
  Next cell2
Next cell1
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: assuming, when sum of first 5 reaches MyNumber, then these what about rest of 25 cells below... ?

Comment: You're right, I think it's better to put numbers that reach to myNumber into column B

Answer (score 0):

Try this; for range A1:A30, if cummulative sum reaches MyNumber, then will color red that range & exit the code...

```
Sub code()
MyNumber = 45
num = 0
For i = 1 To 30
    num = num + Range("A" & i).Value
    If num >= MyNumber Then
        Range("A1:A" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The numbers might be in separate cells

Comment: I need exact numbers that reached to MyNumber

Comment: You can refer the numbers accordingly by changing the for loop & change the if condition to num=MyNumber for exact number cumulative sum...

Comment: Consider if our goal are in a3+a7+a30 cells. Your code not working in this situation